# PHP-FPM processes not dying after reaching process_idle_timeout

Tags: php, nginx, devops

I have a setup of nginx + php-fpm on my server.

FPM's pool configuration looks like this:

```
[www]
user                        = root
group                       = root
listen                      = /run/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner                = root
listen.group                = root

pm                          = ondemand
pm.max_children             = 50
pm.process_idle_timeout     = 10s
pm.max_requests             = 500
pm.status_path              = /server-status

catch_workers_output        = yes
```

My first expectation is, that no child `php-fpm` processes are started unless there's an incoming request. Unfortunately, when I start `php-fpm` I promptly see 2 processes:

```
10 ?        S      0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
37 ?        S      0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

So, one process is pre-forked for some reason.

My second expectation is that all processes idling for more than 10s will be killed. I run a test which results in the creation of 13 processes. After 1 minute or so (no more requests performed) around 5 processes are idling. Why is it so?

Comment: Possibly similar issue here https://serverfault.com/questions/626904/php-fpm-state-finishing-but-never-completes. BTW you should not use the `root` user for fpm's `user` and `group`, but webserver user e.g. `apache` or `nginx`. The 2 processes are perfectly normal for your config - master process and child process. The issue here might be the some process silently dies (will not complete) without letting nginx properly know that process should be killed.